# Keeping multiple terminal windows in focus

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, programming, usability

I write code. I use terminal a lot. I ofter use many terminal windows. I hate how tabs look.

Are there any applications that allow me to keep multiple terminal windows in focus to streamline my development?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try [Terminator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UASSp.png). It allows you to split the terminal window (You can also have tabs and separate windows).

[image: simple terminator usage]

You can install terminator from your current terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Or you can search 'terminator' in Ubuntu Software Centre (or Synaptic).

Comment: Um, wow! Holy crap Terminator is awesome!

Comment: Holy crap I was about to post the same answer. Once you see the terminator you never go back to the puny gnome-terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately layout  of terminator saves horizontal and vertical console not the size of them. Anyone has a solution to save size of consoles?

Answer (score 14):

Both screen and byobu (which is just screen with some neat extras) allow you to use multiple windows within one session.  For me they're must-have applications when I'm connecting via SSH.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen for more information on how to use screen.

Comment: Screen is the best option if you don't like terminal tabs.

Answer (score 6):

Yakuake is like Guake + Terminator: you get multiple tabs and split screen terminals, all in a quake drop-down. But it's a KDE application so if you're using Gnome, I would say Guake.

Answer (score 4):

I also (in addition to terminator) use Guake `sudo apt-get install guake`. It is a quake-like console tool which is basically a tabbed terminal except it pops out when you press F12 and closes when you lose focus (if you configure it that way). I love it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what the problem is. I just opened 5 terminal windows at the same time, no problem, by hitting ctrl+shift+n with the terminal open, or going to File > Open Terminal. I haven't done anything that would affect the terminal... This is pretty much right out of the box. Are you using 10.4?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not crazy... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#More ways to run a terminal

See the "More Ways to Run a Terminal" section.

Comment: just be quite. :)

Comment: I see... You want to use multiple terminal instances within one window. Uh... Why? What's the problem with multiple windows?

Answer (score 0):

Just some alternatives out there:

Try a different terminal. I use urxvt-unicode (package name) and it has a much better tab layout/look imo.

Here's a page with a sample screenshot of the tabs in the upper corner:
http://battlemidget.blogspot.com/2007/10/urxvt-fvwm.html

Secondly, you might consider a tiling window manager at some point. I'm a huge fan. You don't have to worry about laying out all those different terminals and just add/remove as you need them. I'm using AwesomeWM, but Xmodad is another really good one.

Quick youtube of someone using it:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FUkmMeU3bU&feature=related

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have many ssh/telnet connections to some machines, please, ty PAC (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/)  [link text](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/)

Answer (score 0):

Mutiplexing the terminal?

1. `sudo apt-get install guake`
2. `sudo apt-get install tmux`
3. Open `guake` by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.
4. Right click on the dropping window and then select Preferences.
5. Select `usr/bin/tmux` in the only one select box.
6. In my case, I have to close and re-open `guake`.

So now you have `guake` with multiple window display and several other tools.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then `%` for vertical splitting. 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then `"` for horizontal splitting.

Comment: "the only one select box" -- what does that mean?